# Avoid searching database twice in multiple conditions where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, where-clause, multiple-conditions

I wonder if there is Rails magic to avoid searching the database twice in the following situation:

Background: I am searching for orders from a user which are either PENDING or SENT and due today.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
order_array = Order.where(:filled => pending) || Order.where(:fileld => done, :due => today)
```

Now the problem is that this searches the database twice. I'd like to do this in one search and would appreciate pointers into how RoR would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
order_array = Order.where("filled = 'PENDING' OR (filled = 'SENT' AND due BETWEEN ? AND ?)", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Cool! I was wondering if there is a Rails "shortcut" to avoid typing out the SQL text, for my own edification. But this is a really valuable explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below chain condition  -

```
Customer.where(:reseller_id => :map_reseller_id).where(:is_deleted_by_reseller => false)
```